# Can I convert centigrade to farenheit in a query (not a function)

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

In Oracle I can convert centigrade to farenheit in an SQL query, see below. It seems SQL Server does not have full regex functionality. Is it possible to do this without dropping into a function, which I currently do?
(UNISTR('00B0') is the degree symbol we use)

The requirement is for any string that contains [digits]°C to be converted to same string with [new_digits]°F.

```
SELECT replace(replace(v_text_f,replace(regexp_substr(v_text_f,'\-?    [[:digit:]]+\.?[[:digit:]]*'||UNISTR('\00B0')||'C'),UNISTR('\00B0')||'C'),
   replace(regexp_substr(v_text_f,'\-?[[:digit:]]+\.?[[:digit:]]*'||UNISTR('\00B0')||'C'),UNISTR('\00B0')||'C')*9/5+32||UNISTR('\00B0')||'F'),
   UNISTR('\00B0')||'F'||UNISTR('\00B0')||'C',UNISTR('\00B0') ||'F')
FROM (SELECT '38'||UNISTR('\00B0')||'C' as v_text_f FROM DUAL)
```

Comment: Can you move that into your business logic layer? That query looks like a maintenance nightmare to me.

Comment: Whatever happened to F = C * 9 / 5 + 32 ? Is this part of an obfuscated code competition?

Comment: This is a good example of why you should persist values according to their natural type. Temperature should be persisted as a numeric type because you can do math on it like figure out differences or convert to different scale. Had it been a numeric type you could use a very simple query like the one @DavidAldridge commented with.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, comparing to Oracle code, extremely simplified version:

```
DECLARE @C nvarchar(10) = '38'+CHAR(0x00B0)+'C' --38°C

SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10),CONVERT(int ,LEFT(@C, CHARINDEX(CHAR(0x00B0), @C)-1))*9/5+32)+CHAR(0x00B0)+'F'
--100°F
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel, that useful. But doesn't enable me to find the centigrade value in the middle of a string, perhaps more than once.